# How to add selenium webpage on a GUI application with python

Tags: python, user-interface, selenium-webdriver, pyqt5

For a project, I need to display a web page in a python interface, and I need to be able to interact with this web page either with code or directly with the cursor. The user should be able to click buttons with the mouse and the program should also be able to press the buttons using javascript code.

I currently use selenium to run the javascript code on the browser and PyQt5 for the interface, but the browser and interface created by selenium are two separate windows, and I want to turn it into a single PyQt5 window. How can I achieve this kind of result. I tried using the WebEngine module included in PyQt5, but it caused me some problems when executing javascript code (it couldn't get into iframe structures on the web page).

Comment: While it's theoretically possible to embed windows from external processes in Qt, it's usually discouraged as unreliable, buggy and even impossible under certain circumstances. If you did try to use QtWebEngine, then show us what you did with *those* attempts, by also providing a related [mre] and adding proper details about your issue.

Comment: @musicamante I lost some of the code unfortunatelly. But I run this js code in QWebEngine to HOLD-PRESS a button. It presses some buttons while does not presses to other even though it is in the same iframe. Selenium didnt give any problems.
script = """
            var iframe = document.querySelector('#statbar');
            var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var button = iframeDoc.evaluate('/html/body/div[5]/button', iframeDoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            button.click();
            """

Comment: Sorry but we cannot work with insufficient code. Please take your time to recreate a valid MRE as requested, then either [edit] your post to properly reflect that problem, or, better, delete this and create a new one, since the problem is unrelated to the current topic.

Comment: @musicamante I am not looking for solving the original code's problem, I am just asking for advice to show and interact a web browser within an GUI. I could also use other libraries if needed.

Comment: As already said, showing a web browser within the GUI of another problem is theoretically possible but discouraged and unreliable (even *if* it works, **two** of its main issues are exactly *proper* display *and* interaction). The only appropriate solution, at least for Qt, is to use its QtWebEngine module.